# how to extract number in php using regex?

Tags: php, regex

If I want to extract only "7.20" from "$ 7.20", how can I do??
I have try

```
preg_replace("[^0-9]", "", "$ 7.20");
```

but it is not work.
It also shows $ 7.20... There is no difference...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
preg_replace('/[^.0-9]/', "", "$ 7.20");
```

Your regex needs to be delimited, start and end.  Commonly / is used as a delimiter.

What you have above: `[^0-9]`

The initial `[` will be interpreted as a delimiter (in pair with `]` at the end).

This was looking to replace `0-9` literally at the beginning of the string.

Comment: You can use brackets as delimiters, so [] is actually okay, like ().

Comment: @hakre Gosh, I never noticed that before.  [Right you are.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 2):

You could also try [sscanf](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sscanf.php), usually easier to use

```
sscanf( '$ 7.20', '$ %f' );
```

Comment: With `ltrim()` and a character mask of `$ ` you can easily remove the leading unwanted characters.  In addition to being brief and correct, `sscanf()` is more powerful than other techniques because it allows you to cast the matched substring as a float.